# C# Entity Framework 6 ApplicationUserManager delete application user

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, foreign-keys, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to use the following code to delete one of the users:

```
ApplicationUserManager userManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
var userForDeleting = userManager.FindById(Id);
var result = userManager.Delete(userForDeleting);
```

The problem arises because I have a lot of tables in the database where there is a constraint with a foreign key (for example UserId) pointing to a primary key => AspNetUsers.Id. 
So I get an exception that basically tells me that I have another table where a foreign key points to a primary key in AspNetUsers table (precisely to the Id field). I actually want to erase all this data that is connected to this user with the foreign key, so I want to keep no trace of that user.

As I have around 10 tables already connected with foreign keys to a primary key Id in AspNetUsers already, removing the constraints and deleting everything manually from each table sounds like a disaster. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Yes. Make your foreign keys "CASCADE ON DELETE".

Comment: @spender just searched for how to do this: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/cascade-delete-in-code-first.aspx but it says: "Cascade delete is enabled by default in Entity Framework for all types of relationships such as one-to-one, one-to-many and many-to-many." which applies to my model perfectly, but it is not working by default. Any ideas what is wrong?